# How to create .DOC file witih expo-file-system?

Tags: react-native, expo

I just created a similar question regarding promises...

But I'm having trouble saving `.DOC` files.

It comes corrupted when saving:

```
Could not get the file's extension.
```

and is being saved in:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/2021-09-01_5.doc
```

How to fix it?

```
data.map(async (index) => {
  const date = new Date(index.synchronization)

  const formattedDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];

  const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${formattedDate}.doc`;

  await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
    fileUri,
    "Hello World, i'am saving this file :)").then(response => console.log(response)).catch(error => console.log(error));

  const { uri } = await MediaLibrary
    .createAssetAsync(`${fileUri}`)
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((error) => error);
  console.log(uri)
  await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync("Downloads", uri).then(response => console.log(response)).catch(error => console.log(error.message));

});
```